# Order by case AND by name

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql statement which puts `external` as last, but I also want to sort the rest of the results by name. Is it possible to use two `ORDER BY`'s?

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `user`
WHERE `parent` = %d AND `isFolder` = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = \'External\' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: `ORDER BY case ... end, name`

Comment: Yes it is possible. http://gitolite.com/tias.html that generally applies to everything in programming.

Comment: @jarlh thnx.. feel really stupid now. If you want you can put as answer and I accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer!

Simply add the `name` column to the `ORDER BY` list:

```
SELECT `id`
FROM `user`
WHERE `parent` = %d AND `isFolder` = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = \'External\' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, name
```